# Why Firebase Phone Authentication send same code again for specific phone number

Tags: android, firebase

If we logout from our app and try to login again, Firebase sends the same code for verification that was received earlier?why?how to generate different code each time through Firebase?

Comment: Are you using Mobile Verification through firebase? @SAT

Comment: Thanks for your reply,i solved it @Brahma Datta

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Parameter "Timeout duration" , For below code - Otp will be same for a number for 60 seconds

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
        60,                 // Timeout duration
        TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
        this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
        mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
```